# How to Remove Firebase Cloud Function Push Key in Snapshot Data?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to get Firebase Realtime data with Firebase Cloud Function using HTTP request trigger. I've done that.

However, I need to get only its snapshot/children data without its push key.

This is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.showEvent = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const params = req.url.split("/");
    const uId = params[1];
    const deviceId = params[2];

    return admin.database().ref(uId + '/' + deviceId).on('value', (snapshot) => {
        var event = snapshot.val();

        res.send(event);
    });
});
```

That code works for me when calling `my-project.firebaseapp.com/event/123/`.

and returns something like this:

```
"-LYkQIOBzDOmExyw2jPw": {"batt": 3.7, "curr": 5.6, "humi": 68.1},
"-LYkQNMCQcsIYvMVtxD5": {"batt": 3.6, "curr": 5.6, "humi": 68.2}
```

My question is how to remove its push key id, so my new data respon is became like this:

```
{"batt": 3.7, "curr": 5.6, "humi": 68.1},
{"batt": 3.6, "curr": 5.6, "humi": 68.2}
```

Thank You

My Updated Program, now it works:

```
 var returnArr = [];

    admin.database().ref(uId + '/' + deviceId).on('value', (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var item = childSnapshot.val();
            returnArr.push(item);
        });
    });

 res.send(returnArr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have multiple readings for the device. To send a response without the keys, you can do:

```
return admin.database().ref(uId + '/' + deviceId).on('value', (snapshot) => {
    var events = [];
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        events.push(child.val());
    });
    res.send(events);
});
```

Comment: well, it works. But only gives first data (only one data).

Comment: well, i try to insert event data to array, and it works now. Thanks